# UISegmentedControl Within UIToolBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitoolbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I know how to add a `UISegmentedControl` to a `UIToolBar` from within IB, but I am trying to do the same programmatically, because I am using a custom subclass of `UISegmentedControl` with doesn't have an XIB.

This is the code for the `UISegmentedControl`:

```
SVSegmentedControl *navSC = [[SVSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"List", @"Calendar", nil]];
navSC.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:navSC];
[navSC release];
navSC.center = CGPointMake(160, 70);
```

I was thinking of doing something like `[self.toolbar addSubview:navSC]`, but that didn't show anything.

Comment: Note that you *can* create a regular UISegmentedControl in IB, then change its class to your custom subclass. Any properties specific to your subclass you'll have to set up in a method like `awakeFromNib`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the `UIToolbar` method `– setItems:animated:` (detailed in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)):

```
UIBarButtonItem *segItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:navSC];
UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:NULL];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spaceItem,segItem,spaceItem,nil] animated:YES];
[segItem release];
[spaceItem release];
```

Comment: Isn't it necessary to wrap `navSC` in `UIBarButtonItem`?

Comment: @ZhangChn, I think you are right about wrapping it in a `UIBarButtonItem` first because right now, it is crashing the app.  Can you show me how?

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly.  But do you know how I can center the button?  Right now it is showing on the left side of the toolbar.

Comment: @Faisal: You could add flexible space (`UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace`) on either side of the segment.

Comment: Ok I added this: ` UIBarButtonItem *fixedItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:NULL] autorelease];, but how do I add it to toolbar along with the `segItem`?

Comment: @Faisal: See above. Using flexible space pushes the middle item into the center.